# In how place(activity/fragment/singleton) I must realise Observable from retrofit?

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2

I use retrofit2 in my project. I have interface:

```
public interface ProductService {
    @POST("findProducts")
    Observable<ProductsResponse> getProducts();
}
```

and service method:

```
public ProductService getProductService() {
        return getService(ProductService.class);
    }
```

After that I use this service in my fragment. When I click to button I call this method:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
                RestApiFactory.getInstance().getProductService().getProducts()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new ProductHandler());
            }
        }
```

and realise handler in this fragment:

```
private class ProductHandler implements Observer<ProductsResponse> {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe: start");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ProductsResponse value) {
           //save to DB in new Thread
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError: "+ e.getMessage());
            price.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: finish");
            price.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

is it correct to implement `ProductHandler implements Observer<ProductsResponse>`'s methods

```
onSubscribe
onNext
onError
onComplete
```

in fragment?

I'm advised to move this in a singleton:

```
MySingleton.getInstanse().getData();
```

and move all to `getData` :

```
public void getData(){
RestApiFactory.getInstance().getProductService().getProducts()
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new Observer<ProductsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                            //send broadcast and catch in Fragment
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(ProductsResponse productsResponse) {
                        //send broadcast and catch in Fragment
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        //send broadcast and catch in Fragment
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                        //send broadcast and catch in Fragment
                        }
                    });
}
```

but I think this is nonsense. who will tell you how to use it (in what place) `Observable` from `retrofit`?

Answer (score -1):

there is no need to implement Observer.You can just need to create an observer for the same.Let's see the example.

```
service.getProducts()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(mObserver);
    }
```

the observer should look like and must be initialized in oncreate:

```
mObserver = new Observer<ProductsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                mDisposableList.add(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ProductsResponse value) {

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        };
```